# Material-UI @next Does not support props-based styling?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

With the arrival of Material-UI@next comes the replacement of LESS-based styling with CSS-to-JS-based styling.  However, the component demos on [Material-UI's website](https://material-ui-1dab0.firebaseapp.com/component-demos) appear to ignore the creation of props-based-styling.  I'm trying to create `div`s containing various Material-UI components at specific absolute heights on my page, however, the requirement of the stylesheet being predefined outside of the class means that the properties within the stylesheet can't be based on props passed to the component.  Am I missing something?

For example:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {withStyles, createStyleSheet} from 'material-ui/styles';
import Button from 'material-ui/Button';
const styleSheet = createStyleSheet({
    container: {
        position: "absolute",
        top: /*How can this be dependent upon the props passed to the component?*/,
        height: /*How can this be dependent upon the props passed to the component?*/,
    }
});
class Foo extends Component {

  render() {
        let classes = this.props.classes;
    return (
      <div className={classes.container}>
        <Button raised/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default withStyles(styleSheet)(Foo);
```

The example component displayed above can't have `props`-dependent styles, because `props` is not defined when the stylesheet is created.  So how do I solve this problem? ***IS*** there a solution?

Comment: This is not supported yet and there is a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/7633) tracking this request.

Answer (score 2):

I would strongly advise you check out [Styled Compoments](https://www.styled-components.com/). They make styling very simple and even allow you to pass third party components (in your case Material UI components). They also allow you to pass in props like the following:

```
const Stylesheet = styled.div`
    color: ${props => props.primary ? 'white' :
`

<Stylesheet primary>My Div</Stylesheet>
```

Check out the [docs](https://www.styled-components.com/docs/basics#passed-props) for more details, that was a very simple example, but they are super easy to work with and you can accomplish exactly what you need with them.

Comment: One thing if anyone comes back here. Styled components doesn't have access to a lot of material ui properties